# Recursive sequence nth element formula

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

What is the $n$th element of this sequence:

$$S_n = S_{n-1} + (c_1 - S_{n-1})c_2$$

where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants and $S_1=0$.

Thank you,

Comment: Take sequence $P_n = S_n-c_1$ and get recurrence relation for $P_n$ and value of $P_1$.

Comment: @almagest There is no $S_{n-2}$ term, so equation would be $x+c_2-1 = 0$... And I doubt OP knows why that works.

Comment: @Abstraction Sorry, I should have read that more carefully. Odd to separate the two $S_{n-1}$ terms!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the sequence is given by $\{a_n\}$.

$$S_n = S_{n-1} + (c_1 - S_{n-1})c_2$$
$$S_n - S_{n-1} = (c_1 - S_{n-1})c_2$$
$$a_n = (c_1 - S_{n-1})c_2$$
$$c_2S_{n-1} = c_1c_2-a_n$$
$$S_{n-1} = c_1-\frac{1}{c_2}a_n$$

See if this helps.

Comment: This is not clear. What is {an} ?

Comment: @IlanStux $S_n=\sum_{r=1}^n a_r=a_1+a_2+a_3+\ldots +a_n$. This sequence of $a_i$'s is denoted by ${a_n}$.

Comment: one more step is needed for the formula of $a_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as
$$S_n+(c_2-1)S_{n-1}=c_1c_2$$
If $c_2\ne0$, then one solution is $S_n=A$, a constant, so
$$A(1+c_2-1)=c_2A=c_1c_2$$
So $S_n=c_1$ is a solution. Then let $T_n=S_n-c_1$, so
$$T_n+c_1+(c_2-1)(T_{n-1}+c_1)=T_n+(c_2-1)T_{n-1}+c_1c_2=c_1c_2$$
$$T_n=(1-c_2)T_{n-1}=\frac{(1-c_2)^n}{(1-c_2)^{n-1}}T_{n-1}$$
$$\frac{T_n}{(1-c_2)^n}=\frac{T_{n-1}}{(1-c_2)^{n-1}}=\frac{T_1}{(1-c_2)^1}=\frac{S_1-c_1}{1-c_2}=\frac{-c_1}{1-c_2}$$
Then
$$S_n=T_n+c_1=c_1-(1-c_2)^{n-1}c_1$$
If $c_2=0$, then the equation reads $S_n=S_{n-1}=S_1=0$.